# relative image source ember js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

i have a problem with assets path in emberjs(ember-cli).

I have 2 routes: `index` and `article` route, the path for index route is just a `/` and the path for the article route is `article/:article_id`

**router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('article', {path : '/article/:article_id'});
});
```

In the `idnex` template, i reference my assets that are in the directory `public/assets/` with the following : `<img src="/assets/images/image1.jpg/>` and its work great, but when i use the same tag in the `article` template, the image is not loaded, and the cause is that the client(browser) send the request to the server with the following url `localhost:4200/article/assets/images/image1.jpg`.

Comment: What is your ember version? [Deprecation of `baseURL`](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/04/28/baseURL.html) may caused this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but using the `{{rootURL}}` helper solve my problem.
Example in your image tag, use something like:

```
<img src="{{rootURL}}assets/images/image1.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Worked for me after I changed the rootURL to a subdirectory path. Awesome!