# Ember dynamic routes with relative image path

Tags: image, ember.js, relative-path, dynamic-routing

Using a relative image path on a dynamic route, adds the route before the image, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062729/relative-image-source-ember-js/41067245#41067245).

Why is this?  And is there a way to user a relative image path with a dynamic route? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative image path is prepended with the dynamic route because the relative image path is missing a leading `/`.

So, assume we are visiting a dynamic route `foo-bar`. The image path below would:

`/assets/images/foo.png` -> `<protocol>://<host>/assets/images/foo.png`

`assets/images/foo.png` -> `<protocol>://<host>/foo-bar/assets/images/foo.png`

This isn't an Ember.js thing, it's a browser and file path thing.

Consider the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7613355/631730.

Comment: Thanks.  Knew it was something simple. :-)